# What to do with these seemingly contradictional answers to two questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

While looking around for identifying some components on ee.se, I stumbled over the following two questions:

- [Identifying a resistor with implausible or impossible color bands](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98425/)
- [Identifying this resistor/capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125127/)

Both have pictures of resistor like components that very much look alike (same texture, base colour, size, just one band different). They both were directly connected to the mains power, so it seems like they served the same purpose. Yet on one question, most seem to have arrived to the answer that its a pico fuse, the other that its a shunt resistor.

I really would like to find an answer, but all make good points for their case; so what should be done with these questions? When just looking at the questions, one seems to be a duplicate of another, so should they be marked as such? Should they be merged?

I doubt that it would be a good idea to ask a third question, as it would just be a duplicate of either one. But would any of marking as duplicate/merging etc. spark any new answers/insights that will really help to get to a definitive answer? Or could it be even possible that one of them is a resistor, one a fuse? If so, then I have no means to further use the answers to help me in identifying parts in a future case. Should I then leave a comment on both highest voted/accepted answers with a link to each other asking for clarifying on how it can be distinguished?

Answer (score 3):

How about commenting on each with "Possibly Related" and a link?

In terms of figuring out which it actually is, in both cases some reverse engineering will probably be necessary, and not enough info is provided to allow a categorical answer.